# How to position ul list after a label?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I would like to name my `ul` list with a label and place the ul list just after it and not below like the default. My `ul` list is in one line, so the result (label + list) should be in one line.

Here is what I have so far :

HTML:

```
<label>test :</label>
<ul>
    <li>word1</li>
    <li>word2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

li {
    display:inline;
}
```

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/72YA4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that you what to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/jslayer/72YA4/3/

```
ul {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

li {
    display:inline;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `display:inline;` to `ul` as well

```
ul {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/72YA4/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Make the ul display inline and then align it

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/72YA4/5/)

**CSS**

```
ul {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

li {
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the quickest fix I know for this:

```
ul{
position:absolute;
top:-8px;
}
```

hope this answers your question :)